# What's the finite population correction in sample survey

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

> The finite population correction in sample survey is :
>
> (A) $n/N$
>
> (B) $N/n$
>
> (C) $1-\frac{n}{N}$
>
> (D) $1-\frac{N}{n}$

I know that , finite population correction factor is
$$fpc=\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$$where , $n=$sample size and $N=$population size.

How I can deduce from it to get one option ? Please help..

Comment: I believe that's a slightly different fpc. Instead, do you know what the variance of a number raised estimator is for both a finite and infinite population (or equivalently for sampling with and without replacement)?

Comment: No sir...please give more detail

Comment: Notice that $\frac{N-n}{N} = 1 - n/N.$ As already mentioned 'finite population correction' has to do with getting the correct variance when sampling $n$ items without replacement from a population of size $N.$ In one setting this is the difference between a binomial model (infinite population or sampling with replacement) and a hypergeometric model (sampling without replacement from a finite population). Terminology about the finite population correction tends to differ among authors. Maybe some clues in Comments will help you find the relevant section of your text.